# How to set timeout in UDP socket with C/C++ in WINDOWS?

Tags: c++, c, windows, sockets, udp

I've been trying to set a `timeout` in my `DatagramSocket` implementation class in C/C++ for WINDOWS  but I can't, I tried the `setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &timeout, sizeof(struct timeval));` like linux and using the `select` function but no delay happened, what am I doing wrong?

This is the interface file:

```
#ifndef __DatagramSocket_H__
#define __DatagramSocket_H__


#ifdef linux
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
#else
    // #include <ws2tcpip.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    // #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") // Winsock Library, it only works in the microsoft compiler, MinGW ignores it
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include "DatagramPacket.h"

class DatagramSocket {
public:
    DatagramSocket(uint16_t iport, const std::string & addr);
    ~DatagramSocket();

    void unbind();

    int send(DatagramPacket &);
    int receive(DatagramPacket &);

    void setTimeout(long, long);
    int receiveTimeout(DatagramPacket &, time_t, time_t);
private:
    sockaddr_in localAddress, remoteAddress;

    struct timeval timeout;
    bool timeout_set;
    #ifdef linux
        int s;
    #else
        SOCKET s;
        struct fd_set fds;
    #endif
};

#endif
```

The DatagramPacket is defined as:

```
class DatagramPacket {
public:
    // data, len, ip, port
    DatagramPacket(char* , size_t, const string &, uint16_t );
    DatagramPacket(char* , size_t);
    DatagramPacket();
    ~DatagramPacket();
    string getAddress();
    char *getData();
    size_t getLength();
    uint16_t getPort();

    void setAddress(const string &);
    void setData(char* , size_t);
    void setLength(size_t);
    void setPort(uint16_t);

private:
    char *data;
    uint16_t port;
    string ip;
    size_t length;
};
```

The definition of the member functions from the `DatagramSocket` class :

```
DatagramSocket::DatagramSocket(uint16_t iport, const std::string &addr): timeout_set(false) {
    #ifdef _WIN32  // detect windows of 32 and 64 bits
        WSAData wsaData;
        WORD word = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        if (WSAStartup(word, &wsaData) != 0) {
            std::cerr << "Server: WSAStartup failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    #endif 

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    // bzero((char *)&localAddress, sizeof(localAddress));
    memset((char *) &localAddress, 0, sizeof(localAddress));
    localAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr.c_str());
    localAddress.sin_port = htons(iport);
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &localAddress, sizeof(localAddress));
}

void DatagramSocket::setTimeout(long secs, long u_secs) {
    timeout = { 
        .tv_sec = secs, 
        .tv_usec = u_secs };  
    timeout_set = true;
    #ifdef __linux__
        setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &timeout, sizeof(struct timeval));
    #else 
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(s, &fds);
    #endif
}


int DatagramSocket::receiveTimeout(DatagramPacket &p, time_t secs, time_t u_secs) {
    int len = sizeof(remoteAddress);
    if (!timeout_set) setTimeout(secs, u_secs);  
    #ifdef _WIN32
        int sret = select(0, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (sret == 0) {
            cout << "Timeout! " << sret << endl;
            return NULL;
        }
    #endif
    int n = recvfrom(s, p.getData(), p.getLength(), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &remoteAddress, &len);
    if (n < 0) {  // deal with errors 
        #ifdef __linux__
            if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK) 
                fprintf(stderr, "Timeout \n");
            else 
                fprintf(stderr, "Error in recvfrom. \n");
        #endif
        return n;
    }
    p.setPort(remoteAddress.sin_port);  
    p.setAddress(string(inet_ntoa(remoteAddress.sin_addr)));
    p.setLength(n);
    return n;
}
```

I included the ws2tcpip.h and winsock2.h libraries and compiled with the -lwsock32 flag. I'm using MinGW in Windows 10. I already could achieve this task in linux but I couldn't in Windows, I've been looking for an answer in internet but no code worked for me. As I said, setting the timeout do work in linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't see enough code to find the problem. I'll bet you made at least these two mistakes: 1) Did you set the socket non-blocking? You *must* do so. 2) Do you reset `fds` each time? When you call `select`, `fds` is both an input and output parameter, so you want to pass a copy to `select`, not the original.

Comment: I set the socket non-blocking with 
`unsigned long mode = 0;  
ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &mode);`
but it didn't work. Thanks for the second warning. I added more code .

Comment: Did you reset `fds` each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, `SO_RCVTIMEO` takes a `DWORD` specifying milliseconds, not a `timeval` struct like on other platforms:

```cpp
void DatagramSocket::setTimeout(long secs, long u_secs) {
    timeout = { 
        .tv_sec = secs, 
        .tv_usec = u_secs };  
    timeout_set = true;

    #ifdef _WIN32
    DWORD dw = (secs * 1000) + ((u_secs + 999) / 1000);
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &dw, sizeof(dw));
    #else
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &timeout, sizeof(struct timeval));
    #endif
}
```

Also, note that `SO_RCVTIMEO` only applies to blocking reads, not to non-blocking reads.  The code you have showed is not putting the socket into non-blocking mode, so there is really no point in using `select()` if you use `SO_RCVTIMEO`:

```cpp
int DatagramSocket::receiveTimeout(DatagramPacket &p, time_t secs, time_t u_secs) {
    setTimeout(secs, u_secs);  
    int len = sizeof(remoteAddress);
    int n = recvfrom(s, p.getData(), p.getLength(), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &remoteAddress, &len);
    if (n < 0) {  // deal with errors 
        #ifdef _WIN32
        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAETIMEDOUT) 
        #else
        if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
        #endif
            std::cout << "Timeout!" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cerr << "Error in recvfrom." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    p.setPort(remoteAddress.sin_port);  
    p.setAddress(string(inet_ntoa(remoteAddress.sin_addr)));
    p.setLength(n);
    return n;
}
```

Regarding `select()` itself, it modifies the passed `fd_set`(s) on output, so you need to reset your `fds` variable every time you call `select()`.  As such, if you are going to use `select()`, then you should move the `select()` variables into `receiveTimeout()` locally, and don't use `SO_RCVTIMEO`:

```cpp
int DatagramSocket::receiveTimeout(DatagramPacket &p, time_t secs, time_t u_secs) {
    timeval timeout = { 
        .tv_sec = secs, 
        .tv_usec = u_secs };  

    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(s, &fds);

    int nfds;
    #ifdef _WIN32
    nfds = 0;
    #else
    nfds = s + 1;
    #endif

    int sret = select(nfds, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (sret <= 0) {
        if (sret == 0) {
            std::cout << "Timeout!" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cerr << "Error in select." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int len = sizeof(remoteAddress);
    int n = recvfrom(s, p.getData(), p.getLength(), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &remoteAddress, &len);
    if (n < 0) {  // deal with errors 
        std::cerr << "Error in recvfrom." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    p.setPort(remoteAddress.sin_port);  
    p.setAddress(string(inet_ntoa(remoteAddress.sin_addr)));
    p.setLength(n);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your two implementations but they didn't work. I debugged the code where you use `setsockopt `and I realize that it doesn't matter if I call setTimeout function the `recvfrom ` doesn't block in windows BUT in linux it does. I tried to force the socket to be in blocking mode by typing ` u_long mode = 0;
  ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &mode);` but recvfrom stil doens't block.

Comment: @ÁngelLópezManríquez sockets are created in blocking mode by default, on all platforms. Only non-blocking mode needs to be enabled explicitly. That said, `recvfrom()` will block in blocking mode on Windows, if it is not then an error has to be occurring. What is `n` being set to? If -1, what does `WSAGetLastError()` return?

Comment: I expected that, but as I said it doesn't block. In windows recvfrom returns -1 and WSAGetLastError returns 10054. I do not run a server, I just run the client to force the timeout. If I run the server and then the client everything works fine, of course. I call receiveTimeout 7 times and I got the message "Error in recvfrom" with the error code 10054 7 times without any delay.

Comment: @ÁngelLópezManríquez error 10054 is `WSAECONNRESET`. Per the [`recvfrom()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom) on MSDN: "*WSAECONNRESET: The virtual circuit was reset by the remote side executing a hard or abortive close. The application should close the socket; it is no longer usable. **On a UDP-datagram socket this error indicates a previous send operation resulted in an ICMP Port Unreachable message**.*"

Comment: @ÁngelLópezManríquez In other words, you must have `connect()`'ed the UDP socket to a remote peer and then tried to send data to that peer using that "connected" socket, but the peer wasn't reachable, so `recvfrom()` is refusing to listen for packets from that peer on the "connected" socket. You are going to have to "disconnect" the socket (call `connect()` with the `sockaddr` filled with 0s) if you want to continue using the socket with other peers. Otherwise, create a new socket.

Comment: You were always right, unlike linux, if you call `sendto ` but such message couldn't reach the host and then you call `recvfrom` it won't wait no matter what, returning -1 and `WSAGetLastError` returns `WSAECONNRESET` letting us know there's no server available. Windows sockets are a bit smarter in this regard.

I remembered the server was using the `DatagramSocket` AND  `recvfrom` was blocked (I was so focused in the client) so I realized the last problem and then your comment confirmed, everything has sense. I was trying to recreate the same linux behavior. Thank you so much @RemyLebeau!